# Can dropbox-js readFile only get contents of a file of type "text/plain"?

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

I am using the dropbox-js API as a back-end to an application I am creating.

I need to get the contents of a file and I understand that the method "readFile" that is used to get the contents only really supports text files.

I can get the contents of a text file of type "text/plain" i.e. .txt files, using the following:

```
client.readFile(d2.path, {arrayBuffer: true}, function(error, contents){
    var decoded = decodeUtf8(contents);
    console.log(decoded); 
});
```

The API reference for this method is here: http://coffeedoc.info/github/dropbox/dropbox-js/master/classes/Dropbox/Client.html#readFile-instance

The decode function was found here: https://gist.github.com/boushley/5471599

This does not seem to work for any other document type file. If I try and read a .docx /  .doc file the result consists of what looks like scrambled characters. Should it be able to work with other document type files? How would I read it differently?

I really need it to support more than .txt files.

Edit:
This is a test document (.docx) that I tried to read:
[image]

This is how it is decoded (Contents shows that it is indeed an arrayBuffer, while Decoded is the actual string that is returned after decode:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`readFile` should work for any content type. Presumably the "scrambled characters" you see are exactly the content of the `.docx` or `.doc` file you're reading. (If you looked at the file via `type` on Windows or `cat` on Mac/Linux, you would see the same thing.)

So I think the issue you're having is that you want to somehow extract the text from a variety of file formats. Dropbox (and dropbox.js) won't help you with that particular problem... you'll need to find software that understands all those file formats and can convert them to the form you need. For example, [`textract`](http://textract.readthedocs.org/en/latest/python_package.html) is a Python library that can do this.

Comment: Hi smarx, thanks for your reply. I tried reading the content of a .docx file, and I made sure that all it contained was text, but it came out with strange characters - not sure if it has anything to do with utf? I'll take a screenshot and try and add it to the question if you can have a look...

Comment: I think the misunderstanding here is that the `.docx` file format doesn't contain text. (Under the covers, it's actually a zip file with lots of XML files inside.) It doesn't matter what the contents of the document are, a `.docx` file will never have simple readable text in it. You'll need to use a library that understands how to parse a `.docx` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot @smarx. I only really need to read document type files, so should I just rather then support text/plain files for extracting content?